# Texnicenter-classithesis, bibliography not showing bib updates

Tags: bibliographies, texniccenter, sublime-text

I started using texnicenter (TXN) project with the classicthesis latex template for my dissertation. I find myself using sublime text (ST) a lot so I am trying to migrate my project to sublime text and latextools but cannot get the bibliography to show when the build is finish. I have the `%!TEX root = ../mainfile.tex` to all the multipart files. 
These are some things I have noticed:

- When I add new entries into the .bib file they show up in the autocomplete pulldown meaning latextools recognize the bib file (i stand corrected)
- When i build with a new citations that I just added to the bib file never shows in output until I go back to compile with TXN.
- If I clean the project and do a fresh build using ST the bibliography page never shows until I go back to use TXN .
- After I have compiled at least twice with TXN I can cite in ST and build and it will show correctly.

I am adding the lines covering the bibliography below

```
\part{Bibliography}
\cleardoublepage\include{./FrontBackmatter/Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{\bibname}}
\bibliographystyle{./FrontBackmatter/myapsrev_bckref}
\label{app:bibliography} 
\bibliography{./FrontBackmatter/Bibliography}`
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Got it resolved by their support. Changing the build from `traditional` to `simple`in `Preferences >>> Package Settings >>> LaTeXTools >>> Settings` - User got it fixed. Appreciate your help

Comment: Great, please write an self answer, that is welcome here to help other users with the same problem ...

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it with the help of the awesome folks at latextools. Change the build from `traditional` to `simple` in `Preferences >>> Package Settings >>> LaTeXTools >>> Settings - User`